# Example of a unbounded projection

Tags: functional-analysis, examples-counterexamples

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space over $\mathbb{K}$.

Let $T:H\rightarrow H$ be a linear transformation such that $T^2=T$.

What is an example of $T$ such that $T$ is unbounded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example: let $H = \ell^2$.  Define the transformation
$$
(x_1,x_2,\dots) \mapsto
\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty kx_k, 0,0,\dots \right)
$$
Note, however, that this operator is not defined over all of $\ell^2$.

Comment: is the domain closed?

Comment: No. In fact, the domain is dense in $H$.

Answer (score 3):

Also, one can consider an unbounded linear functional $f$ with $f(x_{0})=1$. Then we define the unbounded linear operator $P$ as $Px=f(x)x_{0}$, which implies that $P^{2}x=P(f(x)x_{0})=f(x)f(x_{0})x_{0}=Px$, i.e. P is a projection.