# Must a "projector" on a normed space be bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, projection-matrices, unbounded-operators

In V. Moretti's *Spectral Theory and Quantum Mechanics*, a **projector on a normed space $X$** is defined as a *bounded* linear map $P:X\to X$ such that $P^2=P$. Is the boundedness condition really required here? I'm having trouble imagining an example of an unbounded projector. In other words, if we instead define "projector" as any linear map (on a normed space) such that $P^2=P$, do we already have that P is bounded? Does the answer change if $X$ is assumed to be a Banach space?

---

Note that here, we are assuming $P$ is defined on all of $X$, not only only a dense subspace (as in the linked similar question).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Example of a unbounded projection](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1096785/example-of-a-unbounded-projection)

Comment: No, OP wants $P$ defined on the whole of $X$ with $X$ possibly complete. @JoseAvilez

Comment: @JoseAvilez Kavi Rama Murthy is correct, the linked question is about unbounded projectors on a Hilbert space, which can only exist if defined on a dense domain. But on a normed space, we could (apparently) have a non-bounded projector defined on the whole domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be any  infinite dimensional normed linear space. Then there exists a dis-continuous linear functional $f$. Choose $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)=1$ and define $Px=f(x)x_0$. Then $P^{2}=P$ and $P$ is not bounded since $f$ is not continuous.